# Validation error when missing attribute (undefined method `valid_car_type?' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

What's the best way to handle this type of error? As the mode requires a valid_object, but when it does not get it, it correctly provides validation error for the missing attribute, but then is raises a nil object error on `valid_car_type?`.

This is just a simplified example.

### Model

```
 class Car    
    include ActiveModel::Model
    validates_presence_of :subject :valid_object
    validate :valid_car_type

    def valid_car_type?
       valid_object.car_type == "truck"
    end
  end


 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `valid_car_type?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: This error tells you that you are calling `valid_car_type?` in `nil`. But in your code, you never even call `valid_car_type?` nor it shows how you initialized the instance. Please show the code or the test that lead to that error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use active record call back for example 'before_save, after_save, etc...' and call the valid_car_type?

```
class Car    
    include ActiveModel::Model
    validates_presence_of :subject :valid_object
    before_save :valid_car_type?

    def valid_car_type?
       valid_object.car_type == "truck"
    end
  end
```